# Python regex on list

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to build a parser and save the results as an xml file but i have problems..

Would you experts please have a look at my code ?

Traceback :`TypeError: expected string or buffer`

```
import urllib2, re
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
osc = open('OSCTEST.html','r')
oscread = osc.read()
soup=bs(oscread)
doc = Document()
root = doc.createElement('root')
doc.appendChild(root)
countries = doc.createElement('countries')
root.appendChild(countries)
findtags1 = re.compile ('<h1 class="title metadata_title content_perceived_text(.*?)`</h1>', re.DOTALL |  re.IGNORECASE).findall(soup)
findtags2 = re.compile ('<span class="content_text">(.*?)</span>', re.DOTALL |  re.IGNORECASE).findall(soup)
for header in findtags1:
title_elem = doc.createElement('title')
countries.appendChild(title_elem)
header_elem = doc.createTextNode(header)
title_elem.appendChild(header_elem)
 for item in findtags2:
    art_elem = doc.createElement('artikel')
    countries.appendChild(art_elem)
    s = item.replace('<P>','')
    t = s.replace('</P>','')
    text_elem = doc.createTextNode(t)
    art_elem.appendChild(text_elem)    

print doc.toprettyxml()
```

Comment: Hi Peter; welcome to SO.  Highlight code and press ctrl-k to have it properly formatted.  I tried to remove some of the whitespace while hopefully preserving your code.  If I've made any mistake please rollback.

Comment: Also, please post the traceback if you can; which will show the line where the error occurs. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is here: `re.compile('....').findall(soup)`

Comment: You're probably right, Mark.  But why should we have to guess when the OP can and should learn to use the provided debugging tools.

Comment: Sorry for being new at this..
Have tried to fix the post..
Apparently i can't do a reges on a soup'ed data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good that you're trying to using BeautifulSoup to parse HTML but this won't work:

```
re.compile('<h1 class="title metadata_title content_perceived_text(.*?)`</h1>',
           re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE).findall(soup)
```

You're trying to parse a BeautifulSoup object using a regular expression. Instead you should be using the findAll method on the soup, like this:

```
regex = re.compile('^title metadata_title content_perceived_text', re.IGNORECASE)
for tag in soup.findAll('h1', attrs = { 'class' : regex }):
    print tag.contents
```

If you do actually want to parse the document as text with a regular expression then don't use BeautifulSoup - just read the document into a string and parse that. But I'd suggest you take the time to learn how BeautifulSoup works as this is the preferred way to do it. See the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) for more details.

Comment: ah yes BUT it won't find the rest.. I have real problems getting BS to find the contents from within the tags..

Comment: @Peter Nielsen: Can you explain what you mean by 'it won't find the rest'? Does my update answer your question?

Comment: well, using bs and not regex gives me the problem as to how i find the contents inside the tags and not just the entire tag + content..
Ty for answering so speedy, by the way
:-)

Comment: @Peter Nielsen: "how i find the contents inside the tags". Try this: `for tag in soup.findAll('h1'): print tag.contents`

Comment: Uhhhhh.. very , very , very nice..
I just got tingly all over.. ;-)
Ty very much..

Comment: @Peter, since you like the answer you should upvote and accept it -- this is really fundamental SO etiquette!

Comment: The thing is, though, what to do is one of the tags that I am looking for with BS does not have an end tag ? It would seem that BS fails in such a case..

Comment: @Peter Nielsen: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. I know that BeautifulSoup can handle invalid HTML but I don't know all the details of how it handles missing end tags. It's rather difficult to go into details in comments due to length limits, lack of formatting, etc. I would suggest that you create a new question describing what new issue you have with some examples of how it fails and what you want, then I am sure that I or someone else on Stack Overflow will be able to help you.